# Find the characteristic function of sum of a normal and two compound random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, characteristic-functions

Let $Y_1 \sim CP(\lambda_1,  d F_Z ) $ and $Y_2\sim CP(\lambda_2,  d F_W )$ be two [Compound Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution) random variables and $X = \mathcal{N} + Y_1 + Y_2$  with $\mathcal{N}\sim N(0,1)$ such that $\mathcal{N}, Y_1$ and $Y_2$ independent , i.e.:

$$X = \mathcal{N} +   \sum_{j=1}^{N_1} Z_j + \sum_{j=1}^{N_2} W_j , \quad N_i \sim Poisson (\lambda_i),\,\, i = 1,2$$

I want to calculate the characteristic function of $X$.

First, I will suppose that $\mathcal{N} =0$. My intuition says that $X = Y_1 + Y_2$ is Compound Poisson. In fact:

$$\varphi_{Y_1+Y_2}(s) = \varphi_{Y_1}(s)\varphi_{Y_2}(s)= e^{\lambda_1\left[  \varphi_Z(s)- 1\right]} e^{\lambda_2\left[  \varphi_W(s)- 1\right]}.$$

Since $$\lambda_1\left[  \varphi_Z(s)- 1\right] + \lambda_2\left[  \varphi_W(s)- 1\right]= \lambda \left[ \frac{1}{\lambda} \left( \lambda_1 \varphi_Z(s)  + \lambda_ 2\varphi_W(s) \right) - 1 \right]$$
with $\lambda = \lambda_1+\lambda_2$, we have:
$$\varphi_{Y_1+Y_2}(s) = e^{\lambda\left[  \varphi_\xi(s)- 1\right]} $$
where,
$$\varphi_\xi (s) = \frac{1}{\lambda} \left( \lambda_1 \varphi_Z(s)  + \lambda_ 2\varphi_W(s) \right) $$
i.e.:
$$X = \sum_{j=1}^N \xi_j, \quad N \sim Poisson(\lambda), \,\, \lambda = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2$$
$$\xi \sim dF_\xi = \frac{1}{\lambda} \left( \lambda_1 dF_Z  + \lambda_ 2 dF_W \right)  $$

But, how about the case $\mathcal{N}\neq 0$? i.e., How to show that
$$X = \sum_{j=1}^N \xi_j, \quad N \sim Poisson(\lambda), \,\, \lambda = 1+ \lambda_1 + \lambda_2$$
$$\xi \sim dF_\xi = \frac{1}{\lambda} \left( dF_\mathcal{N} +  \lambda_1 dF_Z  + \lambda_ 2 dF_W \right)  $$

Comment: Please specify if $\mathcal{N},Y_1,Y_2$ are independent (I think you assume they are?)

Comment: Ok, I edited my question.